# Displaying two different subtitles simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video, video-subtitles

I want to add a video to my own site, but what I want to do is a little different. I want to display both english and french subtitles at the same time, like netflix but low budget). How can I do it ? For example, the English subtitle will be displayed in red above the movie, and the French will be displayed in green under English.

Comment: I would have thought two `<track>` might work but if not, then maybe try find `Javascript subtitle parser` in Google search. What file format are your subtitles anyway (_eg:_ SRT or Web VTT)? **PS:** There is also nothing stopping you making your own displayer. Check the text in the subtitles (the time code is what you want) then check `currentTime` on your video player. Maybe have a `<div>` for holding the text on screen. You can use `style="position: absolute; top: YY; left: XX;"` where YY and XX are x/y positions in the div. That will allow to position one above another.

Comment: thank you for answer, i will try